# Get result from chilkatHttp.PostUrlEncodedAsync in VB6

Tags: http, asynchronous, vb6, chilkat

I am using chilkat Http.PostUrlEncodedAsync to send some data to a server and get a JSON response. When the Http_TaskCompleted Event is fired, the task.ResultType returns "object" but there is no task.GetResultObject.
The reply is received correctly (it is present in httpSessionLog.txt) but how do I get it ?

Comment: Are you using VB.Net or VB6? You reference VB6 in the title, but you tagged the question with vb.net.

Comment: I am using VB6, the VB.Net tag is by mistake. Sorry. (Tag. edited)

Answer (score 0):

After a different search I have found it:

```
Private Sub Http_TaskCompleted(ByVal task As Chilkat_v9_5_0.IChilkatTask)
    Dim response As New ChilkatHttpResponse
    Dim success As Long

    success = response.LoadTaskResult(task)
    If (success <> 1) Then
        Debug.Print response.LastErrorText
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Debug.Print response.BodyStr 'this is the response string

End Sub
```